# Retrofit: How do I set a custom deserializer for a certain API calls only?

Tags: retrofit

Hi so i have seen this example pretty much everywhere where they write a custom GSON deserialiser and then its added to the RestAdapter

Basically like this

```
 public RestClient()
{
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ItemTypeAdapterFactory()) // This is the important line ;)
            .setDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'")
            .create();

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setRequestInterceptor(new SessionRequestInterceptor())
            .build();

    apiService = restAdapter.create(ApiService.class);
}
```

But what if my API service cannot use the same deserializer for all API calls? What if i only wanted a single API call to use a speific deserializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know from some tests, you are forced to create two different RestAdapter instances, one with the Gson converter and one without it.